# How to add ASPX MVC View in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015 we are no longer able to add aspx MVC views to MVC project. Anyone knows how to add ASPX MVC View in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Add a new file, name it "MyView.cshtml". Do you want something more than this?

Comment: I want the to use aspx engine in the view. not Razor engine

Comment: Then add an aspx file!

Comment: When I add aspx file, the following error will happen at runtime: The view at '~/Views/Shared/Report.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage<TModel>, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl<TModel>.

Comment: Have a look at an existing view and work out what content you need in there.